# Borel Functions to a Topological Field.

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, borel-sets

A topological field is one with a topology that makes addition, multiplication, and non-zero inversion continuous. Real and Complex numbers with their standard topology are the obvious examples.

Given a Borel space $(X, \sigma_X)$ and a topological field with its corresponding Borel sigma algebra $(F, \sigma_F)$ I believe the set of all Borel measurable functions $f: X \to F$  forms a vector space.

I can't find a reference to confirm this and would appreciate feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Define both addition and (scalar) multiplication pointwise:

$$(f+g)(x):= f(x)+g(x)$$
$$(kf)(x):= kf(x)$$

Now consider following functions:

$$A:F\times F\to F$$
$$A(x,y)=x+y$$
$$B_{k}:F\to F$$
$$B_{k}(x)=kx$$
$$C:X\to X\times X$$
$$C(x)=(x,x)$$

They are all continuous hence measurable. Now all you need to know is that

$$f+g = A\circ(f\times g)\circ C$$
$$kf = f\circ B_k$$

The last function is obviously measurable as a simple composition of measurable functions. $f+g$ is measurable as well because it is a composition of measurable functions as well. You just have to remember that the product of measurable functions $f\times g:X\times X\to F\times F$ is measurable.

In particular $f+g$ and $kf$ are well defined. I leave it as a simple exercise that it defines a vector space structure on the set of all measurable functions $X\to F$.